# USB 32GB empty but says full

Tags: windows-xp

I bought a Sigma 32GB USB pen drive. It is empty but when I try  to put a video file 8.5GB it shows drive full. I formatted it and tried again but the message is the same. I tried with 4GB video file and there were no problems.

Is there a problem in the Sigma or there are some settings to be made on the computer. I use windows XP.

Comment: Is the drive formatted FAT32 or NTFS? FAT32 has a file size limit of 4GB.

Answer (score 9):

The maximum filesize on a FAT32 formatted filesystem is 4GB.  You'll need to re-format the USB drive using NTFS in order to get larger files on there.

Comment: (As a friendly reminder, NTFS is well supported on Windows, but on Linux/OSX most you can do is to read, without other drivers helping. Consider this if you expect portability between Windows and those other systems)

Comment: I don`t see NTFS when format. It shows only FAT 32.

Comment: Check here for more assistance : http://lifehacker.com/5195783/format-a-usb-drive-as-ntfs-in-windows-xp

Comment: @DoktoroReichard - What you said was true a number of years ago but NTFS read/write support has been stable for at least 5 years now.  Of course its still an unofficial driver.  **Besides the user is using Windows XP not Linux so your comment isn't very helpful**

Comment: How to re-format the USB drive using NTFS when there is no such option.

Comment: @Ramhound Just because he is using Windows XP means squat if he plans to use the pen in, say, a friend's Mac or the local library's Ubuntu machine. Most people use pen drives to *store* and *carry* information around easily.

Comment: @user270311 see the link pointed by FreudianSlip. There exists an option in Device Manager that enables fast caching, which is needed on XP to enable NTFS formatting. You can then disable it as the article suggests.

Comment: Why bring about possible situations that don't even involve the author?  As I said Ubuntu has had stable NTFS support for years. As for OS X NTFS that will require third-party software which is ALSO stable.  But both are pointless facts to the author.  He is using Windows XP not Ubuntu or OS X

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I seem to be able to edit NTFS drives on my Fedora Linux installations - huh.-

Answer (score 5):

FAT32 (the default filesystem for most pen drives) has these limits:

- Maximum disk size: 2 terabytes
- **Maximum file size: 4 gigabytes**
- Maximum number of files on disk: 268,435,437
- Maximum number of files in the root folder: 65,534

Notice the second point.

If you want the pen drive to store a larger file then you either need to:

1. Split the file in parts (e.g. `cleave`, `split` or zip in parts)
2. Or use a different filesystem (NTFS is the obvious choice if you are only going to use this pen drive with windows).

---

Answering the comment in the main post since I can not post images to a comment:

- Insert the USB pen drive
- Start diskpart via [start] run] [diskpart] <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Starting diskpart on windows XP]

- use `list disk` to show all the disks in the system, then
- select the disk you want to edit with `select disk #`

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online           74 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online         2793 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 2    Online          135 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 3    No Media           0 B      0 B
  Disk 4    Online         1870 MB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 4

Disk 4 is now the selected disk.
```

- If you only have one partition on the pen drive you can delete it with the command 'clear'
- Next create a new, disk filling partition with `create partition primary'
- and format it with format and fs=ntfs

```
DISKPART> create partition primary
DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.

DISKPART> format fs=ntfs label=my_pendrive quick
    0 percent completed
```

Comment: Can I change the filesystem to NTFS, and how?

Comment: Now answered in the main post